# Scala options pattern matching alternatives?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, scala-option

I've been coding on Scala for 2 years and I use a lot of Option's in my code. I feel it is very clear, easy to understand and can easily be treated. This is a normal approach:

```
val optString = Some("hello")

optString match {
    case Some(str) => //do something here!
    case None => //do something here
}
```

I thought that this was the best way to treat Scala Options, but I want to ask if there's a better way to do so?

Comment: I've always found Tony Morris' [Option Cheat Sheet](http://blog.tmorris.net/posts/scalaoption-cheat-sheet/) to be a very readable reference on the matter

Comment: This is awesome, cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends on the use case. A general pattern I take when I have an option and I need either to apply an operation to `Some` or `None` which yields the same value is to use `Option.fold`:

```
val opt = Some(1)
val res: Int = opt.fold(0)(existing => existing + 1)
```

If you don't like `fold`, `map` and `getOrElse` will do that same trick in reverse:

```
val res: Int = opt.map(_ + 1).getOrElse(0)
```

If I want to continue inside the `Option` container, `map` does the trick.

Comment: That's true, but doesn't this come out as a little unintuitive?

Comment: @SohumSachdev You mean `fold`? I find it very intuitive, but I think that's opinion based in general. I've added another pattern using `map + getOrElse`, maybe you'll find that more intuitive.

Comment: Just note that the `map + getOrElse` is *not* equivalent: `opt.map(_ + 1).getOrElse("foo")` compiles and runs fine while `opt.fold("foo")(_ + 1)` gives `error: type mismatch; found   : Int(1); required: String` as you would expect

Comment: @bojancn To type inference it might be a little more constrained, yes. But is that a useful example at all? What would you use as the inferred type? `Any`?